# Are premodifiers included in the scope of the second NP when two NPs are coordinated elliptically?

Tags: adjectives, modifiers, noun-phrases

In the following examples, where the second NP is elliptical, is the premodifier in the first of the coordinated NPs understood to apply to the second NP as well?

1. A welcome change or addition
2. A mandatory seminar or lecture

That is, in 1. above, does *welcome* modify *change* only, or *addition* as well as *change*, and in 2., does *mandatory* modify *seminar* only, or *lecture* as well as *seminar*?

Comment: I would expect another article before the second noun if it was not meant to be included.

Comment: @KateBunting Right – that's what I was thinking as well. Thanks for comfirming :)

Comment: If you ***do*** repeat the article, that unambiguously rules out attaching the preceding adverbial element *(welcome, mandatory)* to the second noun phrase as well as the first one. But if you ***don't*** repeat the article, the construction is inherently ambiguous, as I'm sure has been queried many times before here on ELL.